# SFINAE with functions and emulating partial template specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-specialization, sfinae

I am trying to make a function X that specializes when a member function Y is provided and if the member function Y is not provided the function X  uses the global non member function Y to achieve the same effect.

I am currently trying to achieve this with the following code

```
template <typename Container, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().y()),
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().y())>::value>* = nullptr>
void do_something(Container&& container) {
    return std::forward<Container>().y();
}

template <typename Container, typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().y()),
            decltype(std::declval<Container>().y())>::value>* = nullptr>
void do_something(Container&& container) {
    return y(std::forward<Container>(container);
}
```

But in the case when the container has both a member function y and the global non member function y also works on it.  There is a compile error because for the second version of the function the template argument is ill formed because a member function y is needed.

Any idea how I can go about resolving this issue?

**NOTE**: This is different from just detecting whether a class has a function of a given signature.  Sorry if the question seems to ask that! The accepted answer below should make my intention clearer.

Comment: @bolov I edited my question and added a note.  Barry's answer below clarifies what I wanted to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical approach is to dispatch to a pair of functions where one is preferred if your condition is met and the other  is simply a fallback. The nice thing is you don't even need `enable_if`, just the trailing `decltype`:

```
template <class C>
auto do_something_impl(C&& c, int)
    -> decltype(std::forward<C>(c).y())
{
    return std::forward<C>(c).y();
}

template <class C>
auto do_something_impl(C&& c, ...)
    -> decltype(y(std::forward<C>(c))
{
    return y(std::forward<C>(c));
}
```

And now just pass in `0`:

```
template <class C>
auto do_something(C&& c)
    -> decltype(do_something_impl(std::forward<C>(c), 0))
{
    return do_something_impl(std::forward<C>(c), 0);
}
```

The conversion sequence to `int` is better than the one to `...`, so if the type has the member function you want, that overload will be preferred even if both are viable candidates.

Comment: This is beautiful.  I had never thought of this.  I had a feeling that trailing return types would be useful, but I did not include ellipses into the equation.  I fell on a shortsighted route.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you stumble upon this technique?

Comment: Ah, just thought of an alternative to this.  An inheritance hierarchy could also be used to imitate the "preferred" dispatch with ellipses here :)

Comment: @Curious Yeah, if you need more than two choices, there are other things you can do. With three you can do `int`, `long`, `...`, but at that point I'd rather have `choice<0>`, `choice<1>`, ...

Comment: @Barry What, you don't like `'\0'` with `char`, `int`, `long`, `user_defined_type_convertible_from_char` and `...`? Heretics! :P

Comment: @T.C. You got me there #Heresy